# Linear map over a vector space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and Let $F_{n+1} [X]$ (odd notation, in my opinion) be the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ over $F$. Define $t: F_{n+1}[X] \to F_{n+1}[X]$

by $t(f(X)) = f(X+1) $. Find the matrix of t relative to the  basis $\{1,X,...,X^n\}$

The solution I have been given

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 &1 & ... & 1 \\0 & 1 &2 & 3 & ... & n  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & ... & \frac12n(n-1)
\\ . & . & . &. & &.
\\ . & . & . &. & &.
\\. & . & . &. & &.
\\ 0 & 0 &0&0 &...& 1
\end{bmatrix}$

My attempts to reproduce this matrix  has not be successful, perhaps  I am misunderstanding  what the map is a doing.

My understanding of the map $t $ is as follows:

Given a polynomial $p(X) = X^2 \in F_{n+1}[X]$ then $t(p(X)) = (X+1)^2 $.

Is my understanding  correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. You should be able to see that the columns of the matrix correspond to rows in Pascal's triangle...

Comment: @ah11950 Why is that the case?

Comment: @ah11950 Binomial expansion?

Comment: Yep, exactly! Does the solution make sense now?

Comment: @ah11950 Left multiplication?

Comment: Left multiplication what? The columns of the matrix in your question are the images of the basis vectors $1, X, X^2, \ldots, X^n$ written with respect to that same basis.

Comment: @ah11950 Of course. Silly me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain how to compute the image of the specific basis polynomial you mentioned, $p(X) = X^2$.  Then $t(p)(X) = (X+1)^2 = 1 + 2X + X^2$.  Thus, the coefficients of $t(p)$ with respect to the given basis are $1, 2, 1, 0, 0, \dots, 0$.  Since $X^2$ is the third basis vector, those coefficients should go into the third column of your matrix.

The other columns are computed similarly, using the Binomial Theorem to expand $(X+1)^k$ for general $k$.